# pip で numpy をアップグレードしても、古いバージョンが表示されてしまう

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip

pandasをインストールしたのですが、実際にimportすると以下のエラーが出てしまいいます。

```
>>> import pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from pandas.compat.numpy import *
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 422, in <module>
        raise ImportError('dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version')
ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version
```

`python-dateutil`(1.5)と`numpy`(1.8.0rc1)をアップグレードするため、

```
pip install -U numpy python-dateutil --ignore-installed
```

をした結果、

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, python-dateutil
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.0 python-dateutil-2.7.3 six-1.11.0
```

と出たので順調そうに見えたのですが、`pip show numpy`をするとバージョンは
1.8.0rc1のままでアップグレードされていません。

当然再度pandasをimportしてみても、
`ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version`
と出てしまい、古い方のバージョン扱いされてしまいます。

宜しくお願いします。

Python : 2.7.10
pip : pip 18.0
python-dateutil : 1.5
numpy : 1.8.0rc1
pandas : 0.23.4
OS : Mac

Comment: 一旦numpyを削除してインストールし直そうと考えたのですが、削除しようとするとCannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.と出ます。

Comment: numpy : 1.8.0rc1 は、MacOSがインストールしたものです。一方、pipでインストールしたものはユーザーディレクトリーの方にインストールされているのでアップグレードではなく2重インストールになっています。他にも問題があると思われるし、OSがインストールしたパッケージを勝手に変更するのはあまり勧められることではないので、仮想環境を作ってインストールした方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy 1.8.0rc1` は、MacOSがインストールしたものです。一方、pipでインストールしたものはユーザーディレクトリーの方にインストールされていると思われるので、アップグレードではなく2重インストールになっていると思われます。

OSがインストールした環境を勝手に変更するのはあまり勧められないので、基本に戻って仮想環境を構築して運用した方がいいと思います。まとめると以下のような手順で`pandas`をインストールできるので、手間は殆どかかりません。

**`virtualenv`のインストール**

```
pip install virtualenv
```

**仮想環境の作成**
ここでは`venv`という名前で作っています。

```
cd 仮想環境を作りたいディレクトリー
virtualenv venv
```

**使い方**

```
cd 仮想環境を作ったディレクトリー
source venv/bin/activate
```

ターミナルの先頭に (venv) と表示されるようになる。そこで、pipを使うと仮想環境にパッケージがインストールされ、pythonとコマンドを打つと仮想環境のpythonが使われるようになります。

```
pip install pandas
```

**仮想環境の終了**

```
deactivate
```