# sympyのupgradeで旧versionがuninstallできない？

Tags: python, sympy

sympyを1.1.1から1.3に

```
pip install --upgrade sympy
```

でupgradeしようとしたら、その時に古いVersionのSympyがimportされていたためか、

```
Installing collected packages: sympy
  Found existing installation: sympy 1.1.1
Cannot uninstall 'sympy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partia l uninstall.
```

というメッセージが出て、versionは1.1.1のままでした。その後、開いているJupyterNotebookを全て閉じてupgradeしなおしましたが、下記のようにやはり`Cannot uninstall 'sympy'`が出ます。
どのように対処すればよいかヘルプお願いいたします。

```
C:\Users\Y-user>pip install --upgrade sympy
Collecting sympy
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\y-user
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sympy) (1.0.0)
Installing collected packages: sympy
  Found existing installation: sympy 1.1.1
Cannot uninstall 'sympy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot
 accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partia
l uninstall.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

起こっていることは、`pip`以外でインストールされた`sympy`が存在しており、`pip`のコントロール下にないのでアンインストールできなかった、ということのようです（以下も参照）。

- [python - pip cannot uninstall : "It is a distutils installed project" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project)
- [python - numpyのアップグレード等について - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47590/numpy%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E7%AD%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

ログを拝見すると、Anacondaを利用されているようなので、解決するかはわかりませんが、`conda update sympy`を試してみてはどうでしょうか？

もしくは上記のリンク先のように、仮想環境を新たに作成する、という手もあると思います。

Comment: conda update sympy　にて問題解決しました。ありがとうございました。